# Creating base image FROM scratch

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I installed Docker Desktop version 24.0.7

In Dockerfile I have the following:

```
# Use a scratch base image for Windows
FROM scratch
# Copy the executable into the container`your text`
COPY hello.cmd /
# Set the default command to run when the container starts
CMD ["hello.cmd"]`
```

`hello.cmd` contains:

```
@echo Hello, World!
```

Build (`docker build -t my-hello .`) seems to finish OK, but running the container gives the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\Dockdir> docker run -it my-hello
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "hello.cmd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

What am I doing wrong? Adding `WORKDIR` Dockerfile didn't help.

I know adding a parent image to `FROM` clause solve this, but I want to create an image FROM scratch in Windows.

Comment: Sorry for the answer, which is **not** an answer, but it is too complicated for a comment 

Comment: Your `scratch` image contains nothing. Your script needs a shell to run and there is no shell in the image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am new to docker too, why did you not provide all info you have done before doing:

```
docker build -t my-hello .
```

The steps might be obvious to an experienced docker-user, but ...

```
D:\TEMP\temp>dir
 Volume in drive D is HDD
 Volume Serial Number is D46B-804B

 Directory of D:\TEMP\temp

25-12-2023  17:40    <DIR>          .
25-12-2023  16:22    <DIR>          ..
25-12-2023  16:59               204 Dockerfile
25-12-2023  17:03                30 hello.cmd
               2 File(s)            234 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  95.182.155.776 bytes free

D:\TEMP\temp>docker build -t my-hello .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
Windows does not support FROM scratch

D:\TEMP\temp>
```

Comment: But I do see the answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58018703/724039

Comment: /me currently downloading 1.35GB+, just to say: "Hello World", and that on [Christmas 2023](https://santatracker.google.com/)  

Comment: Hello Luuk,
Thanks for contributing! It seems you were right about Windows not supporting scratch:
"Because Docker Desktop for Mac and Docker Desktop for Windows use a Linux VM, you need a Linux binary, rather than a Mac or Windows binary. You can use a Docker container to build it"

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/base-images/